# Remove background of Plant Village dataset

Tags: python, opencv, image-segmentation

I’m trying to remove the background from a dataset of leaves, during my research I found out this [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/341285531_Detection_of_foliar_diseases_using_image_processing_techniques) that describes the steps to extract the plant with respect to the background as below.

[image: Steps for background extraction]

However, I cannot understand how to check if the pixel(x,y) is at the edge of Id.
So far, I have implement the previous steps:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import skimage.morphology as morph

image = cv2.imread(filename)
height, width, _ = image.shape
Ihsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
Is = Ihsv[:,:,2]

#Apply Spacial Gaussian Filter
trunc_val = 2
sigma_val = 2
k_size = int(sigma_val * trunc_val)
Ifg = cv2.GaussianBlur(Is, (k_size,k_size), sigma_val)
A = np.zeros((height, width), dtype=np.uint8)
    for h in range(0, height):
        for w in range(0, width):
            if Ifg[h, w] > 0.23:
                A[h, w] = 1

#Apply Morphological Operations
kernelD2 = morph.diamond(2)
kernelD3 = morph.diamond(3)
Ie = cv2.erode(A, kernelD2)
Id = cv2.dilate(Ie, kernelD3)
```

It would be so nice, if someone can help me.

Best Regards.
Tarcísio

Comment: So what is the problem?  Do you get errors? If so what and where? An input and output image would be nice! What debugging have you done?  Please be a bit more clear about the actual problem!

Comment: @fmw42 sorry, I didn't see that it lacks some info.

Comment: Have you got an image for testing purposes?
Perhaps you can try the saliency detection model documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64255472/how-can-i-contour-low-contrast-objects-in-python/67118812#67118812)

Comment: @db_max here you can find an image for testing purpose: https://github.com/spMohanty/PlantVillage-Dataset/blob/master/raw/color/Apple___Apple_scab/00075aa8-d81a-4184-8541-b692b78d398a___FREC_Scab%203335.JPG

Thank you for bringing up the saliency detection model, I will try it!